# Native javascript. Prevent form submit not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a small snippet and can't understand why it doesn't work (Form submitted everytime in Chrome) ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkForm(e) {
        alert('Test');
        e.preventDefault();
    }

</script>

<form id="cart" method="post" name="cart" onsubmit="return checkForm(event);">
   <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

P.S (IMPORTANT) - This code loaded dynamically via Ajax and injected into div container!

Comment: Works fine for me ?

Comment: Not reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/05d0nw9w/

Comment: "Error: checkForm is not defined" --- it is defined in the code you provided.

Comment: "This code loaded dynamically via Ajax and injected into div container!" --- what "this" code? `<script>` nodes are not evaluated if they are dynamically inserted.

Comment: Code above loaded from template file dynamically.

Comment: So what can I do to make it work?

Comment: You can rethink the whole idea.

Comment: So there is no way to evaluate dynamically inserted <script>?

Comment: There is - you can parse the html and `eval` it (good luck with it though).